# Upgrade Firefox in Linux Mint 10

Tags: linux, software-installation, firefox

For some reason a while ago I was no longer able to use the Firefox that came with my Linux Mint 10 virtual machine. I've installed the new version of Firefox (16) using both the package manager and extracting the `tar` file but when I go to `/opt/firefox16/firefox`, it says:

> /usr/bin/firefox: No such file or directory

I also have a symlink so it should automatically go there but I just keep getting that message.  Any ideas?

Comment: What are the results of running `locate firefox`

Comment: In addition to sparticvs, try running `sudo updatedb` before running locate firefox. What is the output of `which firefox` ?

Comment: `/opt/firefox16/firefox` or `/usr/bin/firefox`? Do you have a 32-bit or 64-bit installation?

Comment: `which firefox` is `/usr/bin/firefox`  I think my Linux Mint is 32 bit